# Can i move ownership from Thread T1 to T2 when T1 is running/executing its task in c++ mulithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop

Can i move ownership using std::move() from Thread T1 to T2 when T1 is executing func_1()

I am not sure whether this is the correct way or not? Some one say we shouldn't move the ownership when thread is running. we should do it before running the thread.
Could you tell me what is the correct way and how to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void func_1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "thread_id :" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 2000)
        {
            std::cout << "x :" << x << std::endl;
            x++;
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread T1(func_1);
    std::thread T2(std::move(T1));
    T2.join();
}
```

Comment: Move ownership of what?

Comment: @Raymond : I mentioned it already -> from thread T1 to thread T2

Comment: What is task? C++ standard doesn't define what task is. What is thread ownership? Also please don't distort C++, CPP is C PreProcessor.

Comment: Not ownership by what - ownership of what? What is being owned by thread T1, that you want to move to thread T2? What does "owned" mean here? Can you show some code? Preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @RaymondChen@273K@Igor Tandetnik - I modified my question and added small example please look and answer

Comment: Your code is fine. What concerns do you have?

Comment: @273K: My question if thread T1 is executing func_1() then that time is it good or not to move its ownership to thread T2?

Comment: *Some one say we shouldn't move the ownership when thread is running.* Was it some clown on YouTube? Better use books of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: *if thread T1 is executing func_1() then that time is it good or not to move its ownership to thread T2?* Yes, it's good. T1 does not own a thread. It's just some resource allocated by OS and given to T1. T1 can pass that resource to T2 at any time.

Comment: @273K : ok...i understood what you are saying. for example suppose Thread T1 is doing download operation that time also we can transfer ownership from thread T1 to T2..there is no any problem in doing this you mean...right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some one say we shouldn't move the ownership when thread is running. we should do it before running the thread.

That's simply wrong. There is no problem with moving the `std::thread` object while it manages a running thread. The move doesn't affect the execution of the thread in any way. It just hands over management of the thread to the target `std::thread` object of the move.

Your shown code is fine and doesn't behave in any way different than

```
std::thread T1(func_1);
T1.join();
```

in `main` would.

---

In fact, *before* the thread starts running a `std::thread` object can only either be in a default-constructed or moved-from state. Moving from such a state is completely pointless. So no idea why one would consider that as a use case.

---

Maybe this is a misunderstanding and what you heard was that you shouldn't move a `std::thread` object into another `std::thread` object that already manages a running thread. That can't work, because giving the target `std::thread` object management over the thread managed by the source `std::thread` object requires first giving up management of the thread that the target is already managing, i.e. if it is in a joinable state it must first be joined, just as required by the destructor of `std::thread`.